# Why does Google play hide android.permission.VIBRATE for some apps?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I've noticed that a couple apps on the Play Store are able to make my device vibrate despite not having the VIBRATE permission displayed when installing the app. For example the following game is able to make my phone vibrate if I hit a wall. Here's what I see when installing it:

[image]

However, when I look in settings, I can see that the permission has clearly been declared:
[image]

Is there a special way of achieving this, for example, an additional manifest xml tag,
or is this supposed to be an error on Google's end?

Comment: Does yours behave differently than this?

Comment: Yup, my app only has one permission, and Google play displays the VIBRATE permission clearly when I install it from Google play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all fairness, the Google Play dialog does say "no *special* permissions needed", making it up to them to decide what is "special" and what isn't.

The web version of Google Play *will* list this permission in the remote install dialog while the Google Play app does not and shows the dialog that you posted.

[image]

This is an "error" on Google's end. Once the app is packaged, your manifest cannot be changed to ask for additional permissions at install-time.

Comment: Thanks! Glad that's cleared up. Though it's still pretty weird that Google decides to show the vibration permission for my app in the Play Store on my phone (:

Comment: @ArkhosSeed is your app relatively new on the store and/or is the account that you used to download your app new? It could be a case of google making permissions more visible for new apps and new users (or ofc, you simply have a special app).

Comment: My app is quite new, so you might be right with the case of Google making permissions more visible for newer apps. My account is pretty ancient, however, so the age of my account is probably unrelated.